# How to Create a Lambda Expression using Enum or List?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I want to create custom Html Helper for my model that contains multiple attribute (50 label, 20 textbox, 5 dropdown list, 6 checkbox, ...) which there is some their type is Enum:

This is my Enum Class:

```
    public enum ClassType
    {
        variable1, 
        variable2,
        ...
    }
```

This is The model that contains an Enum attribute:

```
 public class Test2Models
    { 
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "SelectList")]
        public ClassType InitialValue2 { get; set; } 
        ...
    }
```

Now i want to create a custom Html Helper in which i will give the InitialValue2 and i want him to return all the attributes.

```
 public static MvcHtmlString Form<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression }
{
///
}
```

To be more clear i want the call of my custom Html Helper like this:

```
@html.form(it=>it.InitialValue2)
```

and the result i want a list of input

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `Enum.GetValues()` you can leverage this method to get a list of available options for your enum depending on the type

Comment: No Jordy this is not what i am asking for. Thank you anyway

Comment: I want after detection the two variables(which is done i got them) to create my lambda expression.